# Javascript error with sort

Tags: javascript, json, api

i have this code as shown below,

i got this from a developer who went afk because he has family troubles

basically this code below should grab the json results and form them into a table after sorting the price and then placing it in the table.

heres the code

```
//first define a function
var sortTable = function () {
        $("#tableid tbody tr").detach().sort(function (a, b) {
            //substring was added to omit currency sign, you can remove it if data-price attribute does not contain it.
            return parseFloat($(a).data('price').substring(1)) - parseFloat($(b).data('price').substring(1));
        })
        .appendTo('#tableid tbody');
    };
//include two files where rows are loaded
    //1.js
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'api link here',
        success: function (json) {
            //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < json.results.length; i++) {
                var section = json.results[i].section;
                var no = json.results[i].avalible;
                var price = json.results[i].price;
                var button = "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='LINK'>Compare</button>";
               $("#tableid tbody").append("<tr data-price='" + price + "'><td>" + section + "</td><td>" + no + "</td><td>" + price + "</td><td>" + button + "</td></tr>");
                $("#tableid").find(".redirect-button").click(function () {
                    location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
                });
            }
            sortTable();
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
    //and here is the 2nd js file
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '2nd api',
        success: function (json) {
            //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < json.results.length; i++) {
                var section = json.results[i].section;
                var no = json.results[i].avalible;
                var price = json.results[i].amount;
                var button = "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='LINK'>Click Here</button>";
                $("#tableid tbody").append("<tr data-price='" + price + "'><td>" + section + "</td><td>" + no + "</td><td>" + price + "</td><td>" + button + "</td></tr>");
                $("#tableid").find(".redirect-button").click(function () {
                    location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
                });
            }
            sortTable();
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: And what's the error ?

Comment: There isnt one. Thats the issue, nothing comes up in the console, it should show results in the table but it doesn't

Comment: If you remove the `sortTable` functions all together, does something show up then ?

Comment: which, `sortTable();` or `var sortTable = function() {`

Comment: Nevermind, if i remove both `sortTable();` it shows the table fine but unsorted

Comment: and it only shows when i change the table code back to this ` $("#tableid").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+section+"</td><td>"+no+"</td><td>"+price+"</td><td>"+button+"</td></tr></tbody>");` which is what my previous dev told me to change it from this to the one in the code above

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined on top line

Comment: Exactly, that means the price is a number, and when using jQuery's `data` the type is automagically set, in this case to `Number`, which doesn't have a `substring` method. Replace it with `$(a).data('price').toString().substring(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the DOM, to get data that needs to be sorted, is a bad practice IMO. Even worse when you had the results in raw JSON form in the first place (in the success callback of the ajax call). Your success function should do something like this

```
    success: function (json) {
        //first sort the results - or better store these results somewhere
        //and use that as a data store that is responsible for what is rendered in the DOM
        json.results.sort(function(a,b) {
            //using substring and parseFloat just like it was done in sortTable 
            //assuming price field has prices as strings with currency symbol in the first place
            return parseFloat(a.substring(1)) - parseFloat(b.substring(1))
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < json.results.length; i++) {
            var section = json.results[i].section;
            var no = json.results[i].avalible;
            var price = json.results[i].amount;
            var button = "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='LINK'>Click Here</button>";
            $("#tableid tbody").append("<tr data-price='" + price + "'><td>" + section + "</td><td>" + no + "</td><td>" + price + "</td><td>" + button + "</td></tr>");
            $("#tableid").find(".redirect-button").click(function () {
                location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
            });
        }
    }
```